# Click on Python and File in MenuBar of a Qt windows not working on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, pyqt

I Have an issue on Mac OS when I try to click on my menubar, nothing happend. 
I have two menus on named File and Load/Save but when I click on these the submenu don't show up.
Although it works on windows and linux OS. So I'm suspecting something must be done for MAC, but I don't uberstand what?
Even clicking on the 'python' button don't do anything.

Here is a screenshot to better see what I meant:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

and here the begining of the soft:

```
class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        ############variable utiles###########
        self.height_per_line = 20
        self.height_add = 30
        self.width_per_col =155
        self.List_Stim = []
        self.NewStim = None
        self.List_ParamEvol = []
        self.NewParamEvol = None
        #######################################
        #######################################

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.color = self.centralWidget.palette().color(QPalette.Background) 


        # toolbarmenu
        extractAction = QAction("ScreenShot", self)
        extractAction.triggered.connect(self.screenshot)

        extractLoadmodelparam = QAction("Load Model parameters", self)
        extractSavemodelparam = QAction("Save Model parameters", self)
        extractLoadStimparam = QAction("Load Stimulation parameters", self)
        extractSaveStimparam = QAction("Save Stimulation parameters", self)
        extractLoadparamEvol = QAction("Load parameters evolution", self)
        extractSaveparamEvol = QAction("Save parameters evolution", self)
        self.extractLoadResult = QAction("Load Result signals", self)
        self.extractLoadResult.setEnabled(True)
        self.extractSaveResult = QAction("Save Result signals", self)
        self.extractSaveResult.setEnabled(False)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(extractAction)
        fileLoad = menubar.addMenu('&Load/Save')
        fileLoad.addAction(extractSavemodelparam)
        fileLoad.addAction(extractLoadmodelparam)
        fileLoad.addAction(extractSaveStimparam)
        fileLoad.addAction(extractLoadStimparam)
        fileLoad.addAction(extractSaveparamEvol)
        fileLoad.addAction(extractLoadparamEvol)
        fileLoad.addAction(self.extractSaveResult)
        fileLoad.addAction(self.extractLoadResult)

        # set Tabs
        self.centralTabs= QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralTabs)
```

.... Some other stuffs after

Comment: Did you leave out your python code?

Comment: I'm not sure the issue is comming from the code since it works fine on windows and linux. but I add the begining of my code to the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.
Apparently, their is an issue with mac OS regarding to its way to handle menubar. So I set the setNativMenuBar to false in the code:

```
menubar.setNativeMenuBar(False)
```

Like that the menubar is still inside the windows (top left corner of the window) instead being at the top of the screen (detached from the software window itself)